# Elasticsearch multiple terms/filters

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm trying to filter based on multiple terms. I am able to filter if I designate one term

```
[
  "bool" => [
    "must" => [
      0 => [
        "term" => [
          "interests" => [
            "value" => "art"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

But when I use multiple terms I'm always getting an empty response.

```
[
  "bool" => [
    "must" => [
      0 => [
        "term" => [
          "interests" => [
            "value" => "art"
          ]
        ]
      ]
      1 => [
        "term" => [
          "community_privacy" => [
            "value" => "private"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Am I misunderstanding how I should be using multiple terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php syntax is new for me, but in JSON in an array you need to wrap every term(s) clause in its own `bool` and `must`/`filter`/ etc . So in JSON it would be like this:

```
{"query":{
    "bool":{
        "must":[
            {"bool":{
                "must":{
                    "term":{
                        "interests" : "art"
                    }
                }
            }
            },
            {"bool":{
                "must":{
                    "term":{
                        "community_privacy": "private"
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```